# What is the current state of support for 'thread_local' across platforms?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, gcc, clang

I'd like a summary of what the current state of support for the 'thread_local' keyword is across different compilers and platforms.

I'm specifically interested in common desktop and mobile platforms. The information I could find seems spotty at best with reports of it working on some platforms and not on others or mentions of support being a WIP. Answers that confirm support (or lack of support) even for single platforms are welcome. Please mention any caveats to the support if there are any.

- Windows (gcc, clang, msvc)
- Linux (gcc, clang)
- OS X (gcc, clang)
- Android (gcc, clang)
- iOS
- BlackBerry
- Windows Phone/RT/etc

Answer (score 8):

In complement to the other excellent answer: MSVC 2013  doesn't currently support it.

This [page on support of core language features](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/12/02/c-11-14-core-language-features-in-vs-2013-and-the-nov-2013-ctp.aspx) claims it's partially supported. However, looking at the details it appears that:

> Thread-local storage is listed as "Partial" because VC has provided
>   the **non-Standard extension** __declspec(thread) for many years.
>   (Notably, C++11 thread_local supports non-PODs, but __declspec(thread)
>   doesn't.)

It's implemented in MSVC 2014 CTP 3 (since summer 2014; See [blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/17/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-preview.aspx)) and is available in [MSVS2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

For `clang`, you can check the [C++11 implementation status](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html):

> **Language Feature:** Thread-local storage
>   **C++11 Proposal:** [N2659](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2659.htm)
>   **Available in Clang?** Clang 3.3

and

> Clang 3.3 and later implement all of the [ISO C++ 2011 standard](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=50372). ...
>   `thread_local` support currently requires the C++ runtime library from g++-4.8 or later.

You could also use [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/), which is "a 100% complete C++11 implementation on Apple's OS X."

Comment: At present Clang in Xcode 7 for iOS targets does not support thread_local - https://devforums.apple.com/message/1079348#1079348 so I am not sure why this is marked as correct.

Comment: `Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)` produces this fatal diagnostic for x86-64: `error: thread-local storage is not supported for the current target`. But `Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)` seems to handle `thread_local` all right, at least for native x86-64. I don't know about iOS.

Answer (score 1):

## GCC + *nix

GCC supports thread-local storage ([`thread_local` storage duration specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)) since GCC 4.8 i.e. since 2013 March on Linux, macOS and other Unix-likes.

## GCC + Windows (MinGW)

On Windows, MinGW (Thread model: POSIX) however has [a bug: `thread_local` destructors broken with posix threading](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/445/) since 2015 which makes it still not easy to create thread-local variables on Windows.  This includes GCC's extension of using `__thread` storage specifier on MinGW.

Comment: The fact this bug STILL exists as of MinGW 11.2.0 really surprises me. That's indeed .. Problematic.